# animais.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding for a server of RAGEMP and I'm getting the following error:

```
animais.indexOf is not a function
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    var animaisNomes = ["falcao", "golfinho", "gato", "vaca", "javali", "macaco", "coiote", "veado", "orca", "rato", "cao", "puma"];
    var animaisIDs = ["a_c_chickenhawk", "a_c_dolphin", "a_c_cat_01", "a_c_cow", "a_c_boar", "a_c_chimp", "a_c_coyote", "a_c_deer", "a_c_killerwhale", "a_c_rat", "a_c_retriever", "a_c_mtlion"];

        mp.events.addCommand('animal', (player, fullText, animal) => {
                index = animais.indexOf(animal)
                player.outputChatBox(String(index))
        });
```

After i typed the command /animal [some animal] it should return me the index of where that animal is in the list, but instead it returns me the error. Why?

Here's the full code

```
    var animaisNomes = ["falcao", "golfinho", "gato", "vaca", "javali", "macaco", "coiote", "veado", "orca", "rato", "cao", "puma"];
    var animaisIDs = ["a_c_chickenhawk", "a_c_dolphin", "a_c_cat_01", "a_c_cow", "a_c_boar", "a_c_chimp", "a_c_coyote", "a_c_deer", "a_c_killerwhale", "a_c_rat", "a_c_retriever", "a_c_mtlion"];

mp.events.addCommand('animal', (player, fullText, animal) => {
        if (animaisNomes.includes(animal)) {
            player.outputChatBox("Inclui")
            index = animais.indexOf(animal)
            player.outputChatBox(String(index))
        }
        else {
            player.outputChatBox("Esse animal não está disponível.")
        }
});
```

Comment: check your variable names please? `animaisNomes`, `animaisIDs`, there's no `animais`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 7th line of the full code version, you wrote `animais` instread of `animaisNomes`.

Do `index = animaisNomes.indexOf(animal)` and it should  work.

Answer (score 0):

var animals is an object, the curly braces denotes an object {} in javascript.
indexOf would work for arrays and not objects.. arrays are denoted by []. So when you use this function on object it would not work. I would suggest you convert it to an array of objects like this..

```
 var animais = [
        {'falcao': "a_c_chickenhawk"},
        {'golfinho': "a_c_dolphin"},
      ]
```

in this way you would be able to use indexOf but you would need to make changes to accomodate these key value pairs..

Comment: Actually, I mixed two codes when I was copying to here. I changed it right after, but you were too fast hehe